# How to get indexes of groups in a match in regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I want to get indexes of a group in matches in regex. Notice image below:

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edFV8.jpg)

You can see it founded 3 matches. The left side shows Match's indexes and Group 1's indexes. I want to get Group 1's indexes in Python, How can i do it? There is a image below that shows what are Python's returns:

[failed Python code to get Group's indexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xg3BT.jpg)

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of as an image

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass an argument to `i.span()` to specify the group you want to find the span for (otherwise, it just defaults to the entire match). Like this:

```
import re

s = 'aaadaa'
matches = re.finditer(r'(?<=(aa))', s)

for i in matches:
    print(i.span(1)) 

# This will work since you only have one capturing group, but if you have more than one you may have to make separate calls to .span()
```

Answer (score 2):

First to enable overlapping you need to use a lookahead:

```
s = 'aaadaa'
r = re.compile(r'a(?=a)')
```

Then you can use the `start()` method on the `Match` object to get the index of the match:

```
>>> [print(x.start()) for x in r.finditer(s)]
0
1
4
```